# Jquery addclass/removeclass on click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add a class [active] when I click on a element in my menu. Then remove that class [active] when I click on a new item in the menu and add the [active] class to it.

I've tried  `$(this).removeClass("active").addClass("active");`

```
$(this).toggleClass("active");
```

Basically i'm trying to make the hover() function but with the click even.

Edit: Fixed HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><span>Three</li>
    <li><span>Two</li>
    <li><span>One</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please show your markup so we can see the relationship between menu items.

Comment: `$('.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active')`?

Comment: which elements are you actually clicking on?

Comment: Your markup is not valid, you will need to fix it before any jquery will be working effectively. You are closing <li> and <ul> elements with </div>

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming only one `active` element at a time and without further knowledge of your DOM hierarchy.

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

More efficient options are available if the DOM hierarchy is known.

For example, if they're all siblings, you can use this:

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: Your code makes no reference to the list items (`li` elements), which is what the `active` class needs to be added to.

Comment: @Coby the OP had made no mention of `li` items when I wrote this.  The `.menu` class was supposed to represent the hypothetical menu item, and not its parent container.

Comment: Marvelous Solution...saved my lot of time

Answer (score 10):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x7xqb/1/)** — Working example.

Corrected your markup:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><span>Three</span></li>
  <li><span>Two</span></li>
  <li><span>One</span></li>
</ul>
```

Assuming you want the `LI` tags to have the `active` class.

```
<script>
$('.menu li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: you've assumed the elements are siblings - they might not be.

Comment: Can you blame me considering the lack of code/example from OP?

Comment: yes, I can.  It's safer to provide an answer which makes no such assumption, and then show how it might be improved if a particular hierarchy is known.

Comment: In my answer `.menu` was referring to the hypothetical _clicked_ item, not the parent item that it subsequently happens the OP has used in his markup.

Comment: In other words, you, too, made an assumption. In my answer, the hypothetical clicked item resided alongside other menu items. Please don't troll.

Comment: the line of code you're talking about is the click handler and not relevant to the answer, since it's the _body_ of that handler that matters.  In any event, you should _document_ the assumptions you have made.

Comment: p.s. for efficiency your `.on` handler should be `$('.menu').on('click', 'li', ...)` - binding on `document` should only be a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this small lib](https://github.com/Natteke/SmokinSexySoftware/tree/master/packages/Elemental), you can toggle class with native js?
It will be like

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
menu.addEventListener('click', function () {
  Elemental.toggleClass(this, 'active');
})
```

it will add or removes class depending on its presence.