# Upon click, how to select all given elements of a given class that were not selected?

Tags: jquery

Say you have a list with items

```
<ul class = "tabs">
  <li class = "tab tab1 active">
  <li class = "tab tab2">
  <li class = "tab tab3">
</ul>
```

This is used to display content in a div where you have

```
<div class = "tabs">
   <div class = "tab tab1 active">
   <div class = "tab tab2">
   <div class = "tab tab3">
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to select a tab in the `ul` list such that its `div` is set to `active` and previous `active` `div` and `ul` have their `active` class removed.

Is there some equivalent of

```
$(li. has tab in class name).addClass('active' if not already);
$(li. has tab in class name but the ones I didn't select).removeClass('active');
lis = $(li.tab);
$(div.has tab in class name).each(set class same as corresponding li);
```

Or Should I be using `id` in some fashion for this sort of thing?

Really Curious! What is the pro way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Seem to have this working as:

```
$('li.tab').on('click', function() {
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
 $('div.tab').eq(ind).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Saw that method here: [Jquery addclass/removeclass on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295982/jquery-addclass-removeclass-on-click)

Comment: Get all `.tab`s, remove `.active` from all of them, add it to the selected one (`.index()` + `.eq()`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Wasn't sure exactly how to implement that, but found this solution $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); which is working which I saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295982/jquery-addclass-removeclass-on-click

Comment: You don't need any jQuery for this. See my answer below, which is already fully working and just requires styling.

Comment: Ok, will try that out! My class names have additional classes so I guess I just need to modify so that I am using some sort of class contains syntax.

Comment: The point of my answer is to show that you probably don't need most of your classes, and no jQuery.

Comment: I am fairly new to jquery and javascript and really trying to figure out how to go about design that factors in some other things I need to do on my site. For instance, each tab type is associated with certain content type that I have to pull from my database so from each tab I need to know the content type. So I have classes like "tab discussions", "tab chats". But maybe I put the content type as id. Curious what you think. I will revisit your approach since where possible I would prefer to veer away from libraries on top of javascript.

Comment: Did you try toggleClass? https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

Simply assume both have the same index position inside their parent.

Minimal, but working example:

```js
const tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li'));
const panels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.panels>div'));

for (const [tabIndex, tab] of tabs.entries()) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const [panelIndex, panel] of panels.entries()) {
      panel.hidden = tabIndex !== panelIndex;
    }
    for (const xtab of tabs) {
      xtab.classList[xtab===tab ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.tabs .active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.tabs li {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 2px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs { display: flex; margin: 0; padding: 0; justify-content: stretch; }
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active">1
  <li>2
  <li>3
</ul>

<div class="panels">
  <div>Panel 1</div>
  <div hidden>Panel 2</div>
  <div hidden>Panel 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to deal with fact that my class names have multiple classes in them. The approach in my edited post seems to be working, but maybe adds some inefficiencies...

Comment: Since first tab will initially be active, would I need to set <li class = "active">1 and <div class="active">1</div>?

Comment: No, just remove `hidden` from first div. If you want the styling on the button for `.active`, put that on the corresponding `li` initially. Edited the example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See the best thing about the HTML/JS, there isn't one best way. Sure there definitely are worse ways. But better or best really depends on what we are trying to achieve.

According to my experience as Web Developer, and having looked at various jQuery plugins, there are a few principles that usually developers have in place. Something like:

HTML should be structurally be as defined as it can be, so that without even reading the JS behind, a developer should come to know, what this particular functionality or UX is trying to do or will do.

The way I would do this would be as followed, Again this is not the best way. But I'll highlight the benefits of this approach;

First the markup

```html
<ul class="tabs" data-tabable-target="#my-tabable-data">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#shopping-tab">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#books-tab">Books</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#movies-tab">Movies</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panels" data-tabable="" id="my-tabable-data">
    <div id="shopping-tab">1</div>
    <div id="books-tab">2</div>
    <div id="movies-tab">3</div>
</div>
```

> The reason I used `data-tabable` attribute is because, I prefer classes for styling. You could also add a class names `tabable` like `<div class="panel tabable">` and then add your jQuery code to achieve your functionality while also targeting your styling via classes.

Then write my jQuery like:

```js
$('[data-tabable-target]').each(function() {
    target = $(this.data('tabable-target'));
    target.find('div').addClass('hidden');
    this.children('li').click(function() {
        tabToBeActivated = $(this.children('a').get(0).href);
        tabToBeActivated.removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> This would essentially make my code reusable, this allows me to add a separate tabable in the same page. Something like.

```html
<ul class="tabs" data-tabable-target="#my-other-tabable-data">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#shopping-tab">Shopping</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#books-tab">Books</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#movies-tab">Movies</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panels" data-tabable="" id="my-other-tabable-data">
    <div id="hobbies-tab">1</div>
    <div id="travels-tab">2</div>
    <div id="random-tab">3</div>
</div>
```

Really, it comes down to your way of doing it. Just try to solve the problem, at hand. If its something, I'm not going to use once in a page, and just get done with it. I'll probably write what you've written. If its in development, and the need is immediate, I'd use a jQuery plugin.

You should check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs